# Snake body doesnt follow head

Tags: java

i'm working on a snake game in Java, the probleme i have is that the body parts of the snake don't correctly follow the head, it's similar to this problem:

[image: Example illustration of the problem]

Here is where it all happens:

```
public class Screen extends JPanel {

    List<SnakeBody> snakeBody;

    SnakeBody snake;

    Thread thread;

    int x = 10;
    int y = 10;
    int dx = 1;
    int dy = 0;

    Boolean up = false, right = true, down = false, left = false;

    public Screen() throws InterruptedException {

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        snakeBody = new  ArrayList<SnakeBody>();
        snake = new SnakeBody();
        snake.setX(x);
        snake.setY(y);
        snakeBody.add(snake);

        SnakeBody ss = new SnakeBody();
        snakeBody.add(ss);

        setKeyBindings();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);

        g.drawRect(snakeBody.get(0).getX(), snakeBody.get(0).getY(), 10, 10);
        g.drawRect(snakeBody.get(1).getX(), snakeBody.get(1).getY(), 10, 10);
    }

    public void move() {

        if(up) {
            snakeBody.get(0).setX(x);
            snakeBody.get(0).setY(y);

            x += dx;
            y += dy;

            snakeBody.get(1).setX(x);
            snakeBody.get(1).setY(y-10);
        }

        if(right) {
            snakeBody.get(0).setX(x);
            snakeBody.get(0).setY(y);

            x += dx;
            y += dy;

            snakeBody.get(1).setX(x+10);
            snakeBody.get(1).setY(y);
        }

        if(down) {
            snakeBody.get(0).setX(x);
            snakeBody.get(0).setY(y);

            x += dx;
            y += dy;

            snakeBody.get(1).setX(snakeBody.get(0).getX());
            snakeBody.get(1).setY(snakeBody.get(0).getY()-10);
        }

        if(left) {
            snakeBody.get(0).setX(x);
            snakeBody.get(0).setY(y);

            x += dx;
            y += dy;

            snakeBody.get(1).setX(x-10);
            snakeBody.get(1).setY(y);
        }
    }

    private void setKeyBindings() {
        ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();
        int condition = JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;
        InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(condition );

        String vkLeft = "VK_LEFT";
        String vkRight = "VK_RIGHT";
        String vkUp = "VK_UP";
        String vkDown = "VK_DOWN";

        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0), vkLeft);
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0), vkRight);
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0), vkUp);
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0), vkDown);

        actionMap.put(vkLeft, new KeyAction(vkLeft));
        actionMap.put(vkRight, new KeyAction(vkRight));
        actionMap.put(vkUp, new KeyAction(vkUp));
        actionMap.put(vkDown, new KeyAction(vkDown));
    }

    private class KeyAction extends AbstractAction {
        public KeyAction(String actionCommand) {
            putValue(ACTION_COMMAND_KEY, actionCommand);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvt) {
        if(actionEvt.getActionCommand().equals("VK_UP")) {
            dx = 0;
            dy = -1;

            snakeBody.get(1).setX(snakeBody.get(0).getX());
            snakeBody.get(1).setY(snakeBody.get(0).getY());

            up = true;
            right = false;
            down = false;
            left = false;

        }

        if(actionEvt.getActionCommand().equals("VK_RIGHT")) {
            dx = 1;
            dy = 0;

            snakeBody.get(1).setX(snakeBody.get(0).getX());
            snakeBody.get(1).setY(snakeBody.get(0).getY());
            up = false;
            right = true;
            down = false;
            left = false;
        }

        if(actionEvt.getActionCommand().equals("VK_DOWN")) {
            dx = 0;
            dy = 1;

            snakeBody.get(1).setX(snakeBody.get(0).getX());
            snakeBody.get(1).setY(snakeBody.get(0).getY());

            up = false;
            right = false;
            down = true;
            left = false;
        }

        if(actionEvt.getActionCommand().equals("VK_LEFT")) {
            dx = -1;
            dy = 0;

            snakeBody.get(1).setX(snakeBody.get(0).getX());
            snakeBody.get(1).setY(snakeBody.get(0).getY());

            up = false;
            right = false;
            down = false;
            left = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that the minimum amount of code that shows your problem?

Comment: You should override `paintComponent` instead of paint.  Each section will need to know "where" to needs to go next, you will need to maintain some kind "track" of where the head has been and allow the body to follow it...

Answer (score 3):

I think your approach for a snake game is weird .The best way i can think of is a FIFO stack .At each step you add one part in front which would be the head , and remove one part from tail ... all the other parts remain where they are . And when snake bites food you just dont delete a part on next move .

Comment: Yes but i will still have that weird mouvement problem :/

Comment: nope , since you wont be re-drawing the body at each move

Answer (score 2):

All of the logic should be in your `SnakeBody` class (this class should represent the **whole snake body**, from head to tail). This is quite simple if you make nice separation of methods. Hold an array of positions for each element of the body. Then when you move, overwrite the position of the last element with the position of the head offset by the movement delta. (To do this, hold an integer that holds the index of the last body element in the array).

That's how I would do this.